# How to use RavenDB to store database of images

Tags: nosql, ravendb

I am redesigning a .NET system that stores >1000 multipage .TIF images per day for retrieval by desktop and web systems.  The current system uses SQL server to store the image IDs and metadata, but the actual TIF files are stored in NTFS directories on a separate file server.

Would a NoSQL database like RavenDB be a good choice for storing the TIFs as a 'document', and the image ID as the key?

Images are usually written once, but read many times.  I am hoping RavenDB would be a good choice for storing images since I am trying to improve the current system with:
- redundancy (using replication to automatically make another copy of the repository)
- performance (using key/value nature of the images)
- reliability (the current NTFS file system 'database' is error prone and fragile)

Comment: Hi Pete, I see this post is about a year old now and I'm interested to know how you implemented this solution as we are trying to implement the same thing. Did you end up going with a NoSql database?

Comment: Hi Loathian.  Kind of/soft of.  Turns out my original question was due to not really understanding what NoSQL was at the time I asked the question.  I was thinking that a TIF/PDF was a 'document' when it is best to think of a NoSQL document as a JSON package with data inside it.  What we ended up doing with our project was using a traditional SQL database to store index information about a TIF/PDF document, and then using Amazon S3 as the storage for the actual binary.  The SQL db stores the pointer, and S3 stores the doc.  Works well!  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pete,
What you are talking about is not documents, because the images are binary data.
What you can do is use RavenDB attachments feature to store those images.
Attachments can take part of replication as well.

Comment: Ayende, do you think using RavenDB as a primary image store using attachments is the right idea?  I don't want to force a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: RavenDB 3.0 comes with RavenFS, a virtual file system that might work well for this scenario http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/file-system/what-is-raven-fs